# Why does <span> break outside <div> when margin and padding is applied?

Tags: html, css

I know this is very basic CSS. How do I keep the span contained within the div? At the moment, the span extends outside the top and bottom of the div.

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: #ff0;
}
span {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #fc0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <span>span</span>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

To answer your question, this isn't just an issue with `padding` or `margin`, but also with [`width`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#the-width-property), [`display`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#display-prop), and the [box model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html).

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JUbkt/1/)

```
span {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

This will honor any padding, margins, or widths you apply to the span.

Comment: That's interesting. It does honor the padding and margin as you say. However, I actually want the span to extend across the width of it's parent div. Should I apply width to the span?

Comment: @user1405195 Yes, applying a width to the span will achieve your desired result. With your 5px margin and padding, applying 180px width to the span should work.

Comment: @user1405195 I updated the jsFiddle to demonstrate how width works with inline-block elements.

Comment: Well if you set both widths the exact same then span breaks out of parent div. the only honoring is a manual offset of widths.

Answer (score 3):

Inline elements will not consume vertical padding and margin space.  You can make the span `display: block`, but without more detail I don't know if that will achieve your goal.

Comment: Thanks Matthew. Doing that seems to apply the vertical padding but not the margin.

Answer (score 0):

The vertical padding, border and margin of an inline, non-replaced box (e.g. span) start at the top and bottom of the content area, and has nothing to do with the 'line-height'. But only the 'line-height' is used when calculating the height of the line box. Therefore you see an overlapping here: http://jsfiddle.net/Q9AED/

If you want to use a straightforward solution, you can use line-height rather than display: inline-block: [using line-height](http://jsfiddle.net/Q9AED/1/).

display: inline-block works in Safari >= 2, Opera >= 9, IE >= 8, Firefox > 3. But you can imitate an inline-block in IE < 8: display: inline; zoom: 1.